# Julia: How to write fast fuctions modifying structure fields?

Tags: matrix, julia

I want to write efficient methods working with matricies held inside some data structres. I have tested two identical functions for outer product, one operates on ordinary matrix, and another on structure field. The second function runs ~25 times slower:

```
mutable struct MyMatrix{T<:Real}
    mtx::Array{T}
    MyMatrix{T}(len) where T<:Real = new(Array{T}(len, len))
end

function outerprod!(M::MyMatrix{T}, x1::Vector{T}, x2::Vector{T}) where T<:Real
    # mtx = M.mtx - using local reference doesn't help
    len1 = length(x1)
    len2 = length(x2)
    size(M.mtx,1) == len1 && size(M.mtx,2) == len2 || error("length mismatch!")
    for c=1:len2, r=1:len1
        M.mtx[r,c] = x1[r]*x2[c]
    end
    M
end

function outerprod!(mtx::Array{T}, x1::Vector{T}, x2::Vector{T}) where T<:Real
    len1 = length(x1)
    len2 = length(x2)
    size(mtx,1) == len1 && size(mtx,2) == len2 || error("length mismatch!")
    for c=1:len2, r=1:len1
        mtx[r,c] = x1[r]*x2[c]
    end
    mtx
end

N = 100;
v1 = collect(Float64, 1:N)
v2 = collect(Float64, N:-1:1)
m = Array{Float64}(100,100)
M = MyMatrix{Float64}(100)

@time outerprod!(M,v1,v2);
>>  0.001334 seconds (10.00 k allocations: 156.406 KiB)

@time outerprod!(m,v1,v2);
>>  0.000055 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

Finally, when I wrote the third version, referencing the fast function, it worked as fast on structure:

```
function outerprod_!(M::MyMatrix{T}, x1::Vector{T}, x2::Vector{T}) where T<:Real
    outerprod!(M.mtx, x1, x2)
    M
end

@time outerprod_!(M,v1,v2);
>>  0.000058 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

What's wrong with the first function?

P.S. Struggled on this problem for some amount of time, loking for different optimizations in julia, and finally found this.

Comment: MyMatrix remains ambiguous regarding rank of array (i.e. vector, matrix or higher dimension array). Changing: `mtx::Array{T}` to `mtx::Matrix{T}` and `new(Array{T}(len, len))` to `new(Matrix{T}(len, len))` fixes this and makes both versions run about the same time (discovered using `@code_warntype  outerprod!(M,v1,v2);`).

Comment: Tried to run `@code_warntype outerprod!(M,v1,v2);` and get confused with its output. What text from `@code_warntype` actually says that some array is copied instead of referencing?

Comment: Also, noticed that if the second function is `@inline`, `outerprod_!` runs slow again.

Comment: Regarding `@code_warntype` output, it is color coded. The red (on a proper terminal) should require most attention. See [relevant doc](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#man-code-warntype-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `Array{<:Real}` isn't a concrete type:

```julia
julia> Array{<:Real}
Array{#s29,N} where N where #s29<:Real
```

This type includes any possible `N`, instead you're really interested in matrices, so it should be `Array{T, 2}`, or, easier to type and understand, `Matrix{T}`.  In addition, note that your `MyMatrix` type can be immutable: in an immutable struct you can't set the fields, but if the fields are themselves mutable you can set their inner fields.  Furthermore, the `for`-loop can gain a speed-up by using `@inbounds`:

```julia
struct MyMatrix{T<:Real}
    mtx::Matrix{T}
    MyMatrix{T}(len) where T<:Real = new(Array{T}(len, len))
end

function outerprod!(M::MyMatrix{T}, x1::Vector{T}, x2::Vector{T}) where T<:Real
    # mtx = M.mtx - using local reference doesn't help
    len1 = length(x1)
    len2 = length(x2)
    size(M.mtx,1) == len1 && size(M.mtx,2) == len2 || error("length mismatch!")
    @inbounds for c=1:len2, r=1:len1
        M.mtx[r,c] = x1[r]*x2[c]
    end
    M
end

function outerprod!(mtx::Array{T}, x1::Vector{T}, x2::Vector{T}) where T<:Real
    len1 = length(x1)
    len2 = length(x2)
    size(mtx,1) == len1 && size(mtx,2) == len2 || error("length mismatch!")
    @inbounds for c=1:len2, r=1:len1
        mtx[r,c] = x1[r]*x2[c]
    end
    mtx
end

N = 100;
v1 = collect(Float64, 1:N)
v2 = collect(Float64, N:-1:1)
m = Matrix{Float64}(100,100)
M = MyMatrix{Float64}(100)
```

Test the speed:

```julia
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime outerprod!(m,v1,v2);
  2.746 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime outerprod!(M,v1,v2);
  2.746 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```